# Live SQL problems in storing procedures and triggers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problems into applying a storing procedure to my database.
In my order_table I have the following attributes order_table(orderID, quantity, price, discount).
I need to set the discount value to 'Yes' and the price to 15% discount whenever the quantity is more the 500.
I was trying to use a trigger using the following syntax:

```
create trigger discount_t
before insert or update on order_table
for each row
begin
if quantity > 500
then (discount = 'Yes') and (price = price - ((price*15)/100);
end if;
end;
```

When using this syntax I get the following error:

```
Errors: TRIGGER DISCOUNT_T
Line/Col: 3/15 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;

Line/Col: 3/59 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and or
   || year day
```

I am not really familiar with Oracle/Live SQL so anyone knows what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:new` bind variable to refer to the new values for the row and `:=` for assignment in PL/SQL:

```sql
create trigger discount_t
before insert or update on order_table
for each row
begin
  if :NEW.quantity > 500 then
    :NEW.discount := 'Yes';
    :NEW.price := 0.85 * :NEW.price;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Then, for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE order_table (
  quantity NUMBER,
  discount VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'No',
  price    NUMBER
);
```

If you:

```sql
INSERT INTO order_table (quantity, price) VALUES (1000, 100);

SELECT * FROM order_table;
```

Then the output is:

> | QUANTITY | DISCOUNT | PRICE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1000 | Yes | 85 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d1a3a08ca2bcc02dd331ce9593eaad0)*